# Spring Boot: JPA QueryDSL: How to Make a Named Delete?

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, querydsl

In the QueryDSL repository, I can make a named query in this way:

```
public interface HistoricalDataRepository
    extends PagingAndSortingRepository<HistoricalData, Long>, 
            QueryDslPredicateExecutor<HistoricalData> {

    List<HistoricalData> findAll(Predicate predicate);

    HistoricalData findByKeyAndDate(String key, String date);

    @Query(value = "SELECT * FROM historical_data h WHERE "
        + " h.key = :key "
        + " AND h.date <= :date "
        + " order by date desc"
        + " limit 1"
        , nativeQuery = true)
    HistoricalData myFindByKeyLowerOrEqualToDate(
        @Param("key") String key
        , @Param("date") Date date
);
```

How can I perform a

```
DELETE FROM HISTORICAL_DATA;
```

If I use the same syntax as above (with the `@Query`annotation), I get an exception:

```
org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: 
could not extract ResultSet; nested exception is 
org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not extract ResultSet
```

Background: I do not want to use a

```
historicalDataRepository.deleteAll();
```

as this has a VERY low performance.

**EDIT:**

My syntax would look like the following:

```
@Query(value = "DELETE FROM HISTORICAL_DATA", nativeQuery = true)
void myDeleteAll();
```

Comment: If you are open to extending your repository from `JpaRepository` (which extends `PagingAndSortingRepository`), `JpaRepository` provides a `deleteAllInBatch` method. If not, please add the code for the method to which you added the shown query.

Comment: I added the code.

Comment: Have you marked the `myDeleteAll` method with `@Modifying` and `@Transactional`? Make sure to read [the official documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.modifying-queries) to understand nuances around queries that are likely to modify the underlying data.

Comment: I tried to help somebody today with this. @query mechanism is for generating queries, rows. It checks the method signature for the first By and the generates a QUERY with the remaining signature. Section 4.4.2 of the JPA reference.

Comment: Take this with a grain of salt but: if there is a bug in the deleting method how do you recover? Or how do you find out? One thing is missing a row in a list of movies and another is deleting the wrong user.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like, you are combining both JPA query as well as native query. For the syntax you have given, you have to specify it as native as shown below

```
@Query(value = "DELETE FROM HISTORICAL_DATA", nativeQuery = true)
```

Comment: this leads to a runtime error as written in the question.